# How to flatten a nested mongoose 'find' query only on the first level

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have written a mongoose `find` query for the following schema

```
{
  _id: "12345678",
  date: 2021-08-16T04:26:18.000Z,
  en: {
    title: "some title",
    subtitle: "some subtitle",
    content: [
      {
         main: "some content",
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

I want to return `_id`, `date` and everything inside `en` key, so it would look like this:

```
{
  _id: "12345678",
  date: 2021-08-16T04:26:18.000Z,
  title: "some title",
  subtitle: "some sub title",
  content: [
    {
       main: "some content",
    },
  ], 
}
```

I'm wondering if I can do that using `select` `populate` or any other method in mongoose. I'm using express js in my backend.

This is my current query:

```
exports.post_list = function (req, res, next) {
    PostSchema.find(
      { visible: true },
      { visible: 0, es: 0 },
      function (err, posts) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(posts);
      }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this for sure
**Try this**

let searchValue="";

let requestCondition = [{Add your conditions here}];//_id:1
let regex = new RegExp(searchValue,'i');//i is a flag

```
    requestCondition.push({$or: [
            { "_id": { $regex: regex } },
            { "_date": { $regex: regex } },
            { "_title": { $regex: regex } },
            { "subtitle": { $regex: regex } },
            { "contents": { $regex: regex } }
        ]});
}
requestCondition = {$and: requestCondition}
let result = await modelName.find(requestCondition)
    .sort( { _id : -1 } )
    .skip(pg.skip)
    .limit(pg.pageSize)
    .exec();

let total = await modelName.find(requestCondition).countDocuments();
return {
    "pagination":CallYourPaginationObject(pg.pageNo,pg.pageSize,pg.skip,total,result.length),
    "data":result
};
```

}

Comment: Thanks @muhammad, not sure if I'm following but I've updated my question and added the current query that I'm using. It's a simple query without any pagination and search query. Is my current query aligns with your solution?

Comment: you can either use project() function of mongoose OR you can output the result manually using posts.fieldNameYouWant .

Answer (score 0):

you can write a recursive function to do this. or you can simply write a projection in your mongodb query to return just the en and _id.
for additinal information about mongo project read this article.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. Thanks to Muhammad Mujtaba Shafique and Amir Almian for their comments

```
PostSchema.find(
{ visible: true },
{
  _id: 1,
  date: 1,
  title: '$en.title',
  subtitle: '$en.subtitle',
  content: '$en.content',
},
function (err, posts) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  res.send(posts);
}
);
```